# function in Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, function, azure-resource-manager

I need help determining the number of disks in an Azure ARM template with a vmSize parameter.  For example, if vmSize is "small", then set # of disks for the VM to 1, if "medium", then 2 and if "large" then 3, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  I would recommend building a variable object for your names and corresponding sizes and then looking up the corresponding value in a separate variable like this:

```
"vmSizeReference": 
         {
          "small": 1,
          "medium": 2,
          "large": 3
          },
"vmSizeValue":"[variables('vmSizeReference')[parameters('vmSize']]"
```

Then when building your VMs reference `parameters('vmSizeValue')`